# Is it possible to rebase and edit a git commit without using interactive rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

I use git rebase -i on a regular basis and I was hoping to find a way to speed up the process.

For example, I want to edit the 2nd-newest commit in my git history.
I could use:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

... and then set the commit to 'e' and save

I would prefer to be able to do something like:

```
git rebase edit HEAD~2
```

Can rebase be used in this way?

Comment: If you script it, as shown below, beware of a  `git log` is during a reword of an interactive rebase: see "[`git rebase -i` shows wrong commit history after a rebase and force push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362522/6309)".  
Use Git 2.24+ (Q4 2019).

Comment: I submitted a patch that does this, but I didn't pursue it aggressively. I should pick it up again.  https://public-inbox.org/git/20190422000712.13584-1-phil.hord@gmail.com/

Comment: Hey @PhilHord. Just wanted to know, if theres been any on progress on this. This would be a really helpful feature to have. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly, but you could write a script to do this, because `git rebase -i` invokes two *different* editors.  More precisely, it first invokes the *sequence editor* on the set of `pick` commands, and then invokes the *core editor* for files for which you have changed `pick` to either `edit` or `reword`.

Thus, by setting the sequence editor to a different command than your normal interactive editor, you can make an interactive rebase interact less than usual.  (You can also tweak your core editor setting so that it does not interact at all, even when behaving interactively.)

The sequence editor is taken from `$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` if set, or `git config --get sequence.editor`, or using the standard fallback.  The core editor is taken from `$GIT_EDITOR` if set, or `git config --get core.editor`, or using the standard fallback.

The standard fallback is to use `$VISUAL`, or if that is not set, use `$EDITOR`, or if that is not set, use a compiled-in default (often `vi` or `vim`).

Putting this all together (and using bits from [`git-sh-setup`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-sh-setup.html)), I wrote the following completely untested script to *reword* (not amend) commits.  It should be obvious how to rework it to allow amending (editing) commits.

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# git-reword: use git rebase -i to reword one particular commit

SUBDIRECTORY_OK=Yes
USAGE="<commit>"

. $(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup

case $# in
1) ;;
*) usage;;
esac

rev=$(git rev-parse "$1") || exit 1
# We now know which commit to reword; find it relative to HEAD,
# and find the parent argument to pass to "git rebase -i".

# If we wanted to allow multiple rewords we would need to sort
# them topologically so as to find the correct parent argument.
# "git rev-list --no-walk --topo-order <rev> <rev> ..." can do this
# now, but watch out, older rev-lists do not apply the sort if there
# are specific revisions listed on the command line.

if ! git merge-base --is-ancestor $rev HEAD; then
    fatal "$1 is not an ancestor of HEAD, cannot reword by rebasing"
fi
# Is it the root commit?  Are there merges between it and HEAD?
if parent=$(git rev-parse -q --verify ${rev}^); then
    # it has a (first) parent, so don't need --root
    nmerge=$(git rev-list --count --merges $parent..HEAD)
else
    # it has no first parent, so use --root instead
    parent="--root"
    nmerge=$(git rev-list --count --merges HEAD)
fi

# Refuse to run if there are merges.  This is partly a matter
# of taste since we could attempt to combine -i and -p (since
# we are not deleting any pick lines) but it's definitely safer
# to refuse to re-do merges: we don't know if there are evil
# merges, for instance, nor want to force manual re-merges.

if [ $nmerge -gt 0 ]; then
    [ $nmerge -gt 1 ] && msg="are $nmerge merges" || msg="is a merge"
    fatal "Cannot reword: there $msg in the way."
fi

require_clean_work_tree "reword" "Please commit or stash them."

# If we allowed merges, the pick line we want might not be
# the very first pick command; but we don't, so it is, so
# that makes our "editor" pretty easy.

# If we want to allow multiple reword hashes, change this
# to write a script that reads each line and matches SHA-1s
# (we need to expand them a la git-rebase--interactive and
# then match them against the IDs we'd like to reword).

TF=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $TF" 0 1 2 3 15
cat << END > $TF
#! /bin/sh
# change first line from "pick ..." to "reword ..."
# copy the remaining lines unchanged
sed -e '1s/^pick/reword/'
END
chmod +x $TF
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=$TF git rebase -i $parent
```